# How to add one more style based on condition inside this style binding? Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can i add one more extra style but with condition inside the current style binding?

```
:style="{ 'background-color': bgColor, color: fColor }"
```

Son inside this binding I need to add one more style borderBottom:2px based on isInCheckout condition. I don't want to use extra computed. Is there any way to implement it in the above inline binding?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Specifically I'm wondering if you've tried ```:style="(condition) ? { 'background-color': bgColor, color: fColor } : {<other style>}"``` OR ```:style="(condition) => ( (condition) ? { 'background-color': bgColor, color: fColor } : {<other style>})"```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a single computed property for all styles of this element. for example:

```
elementStyle(){
      const style = {}
      if(condition1){
        style['background-color'] = backgroundColorValue
      }
      if(condition2){
        style['color'] = colorValue
      }
      if(condition3){
        style['border-bottom'] = borderBottomValue
      }
      ....
      return style
    }
```

and in the template just do

```
:style="elementStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

In template

```
:style="styles"
```

In script

```
computed: {
  styles() {
    return isInCheckout
     ? { backgroundColor: bgColor, color: fColor, borderBottom: '2px' }
     : { 'background-color': bgColor, color: fColor }

  }
}
```